# Upgrade network protocol to http/2

Tags: spring, http, ssl, apple-push-notifications, http2

I want to push notifications to APNs with spring (server side).
APNs must work with HTTP\2, I have HTTP\1.1
I want to upgrade protocol in my local.
I googled it but not found a clear way.
How to do it? Which steps?